# scalar triple product for continuous functions

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, cross-product

How is the scalar triple product for continuous functions,  rather than vectors? Can it also be written using the integral of the product of three continuous functions?

Comment: Not really because the cross product is not defined in general this way. What does it mean $f\times g$?

Comment: Presumably it is defined pointwise?